# Cannot use Google Drive in my Google online account

Tags: kubuntu, google, online-accounts, google-drive

I want to access files at my Google Drive from Kubuntu 23.04 I'm running. The problem is that when I add Google online account, it allows me to upload files to Youtube only, no traces of Google Drive anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

WMBR, George Hazan

[image: Text]

Answer (score 2):

Install the `kio-gdrive` package with `sudo apt install kio-gdrive`, reopen system settings, and try again.

Afterwards, Google Drive should show up in the network folder of Dolphin file manager.

[KIO-Gdrive webpage](https://community.kde.org/KIO_GDrive#Debian/KDE_neon/Kubuntu_(and_other_Debian_derivatives))

Comment: Thanks, after that I had to remove the existing account and readd it from scratch, and then GDrive appeared. Thanks alot

Comment: Grrm... the next question is how to make a persistent connection to Google. Right now the access token gets expired in about 5 minutes, then I have to readd an account again & again.

`$ kioclient5 exec gdrive:/`

`kf.service.services: KApplicationTrader: mimeType "x-scheme-handler/gdrive" not found`

`"userActionFinished error: 10"

kf5.kio.gdrive: GetCredentialsJob failed: "userActionFinished error: 10"`

`kf.kio.core: KIO::get didn't emit a mimetype! Please fix the KIO worker for URL QUrl("gdrive:/")`

Comment: aha, KWalletManager solved the problem

Comment: @GeorgeHazan Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1470871/edit) my answer and add more details of how you solved it, so that it helps future users

Comment: done. it's on your review now

Comment: Does it still say it's in review? It does not show me anything about review at all

Comment: Yes, it seems so, at least I don't see my changes at this page